# Remove item from array according to condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array (given below). I want to remove files, if `minified` version of the same file exist.

```js
var files = ["foo.js", "foo.min.js", "bar.css","bar.min.css"];

// Should return: [foo.min.js", "bar.min.css"]
```

```js
var files = ["foo.js", "foo.min.js", "bar.css"];

// Should return: [foo.min.js", "bar.css"]
```

## What i have tried

```js
var files = ["foo.js", "bar.css"];

var tempUnMinified = [];
var tempMinified = [];
files.forEach(function (file) {
  if (file.endsWith(".min.js") || file.endsWith(".min.css")) {
    tempMinified.push(file);
  } else {
    tempUnMinified.push(file);
  }
});

tempUnMinified.forEach(function (unMinFile) {
  var tempRf = unMinFile.replace(".js", ".min.js").replace(".css", ".min.css");
  if (files.includes(tempRf)) {
    files.splice(files.indexOf(unMinFile), 1);
  }
});

console.log(files);
```

What i have tried does works, but i'm not sure if it works every time

and so on.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your logic seems to be working fine. I donot find any scenario in which this fails. You can provide the test data for which this solution fails, so that the issue can be fixed (if any)

Comment: `unMinFile.replace(".js", ".min.js").replace(".css", ".min.css")` would fail the logic in case for some reason the file name itself contains ".js" or ".css" not in the end. This can be solved with a Regex that accounts for the end of string. Other than that I don't see a problem, though edge cases are hard to predict - that's what tests are for. Also it seems the code could be optimized but for short lists it wouldn't be a real issue.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions? Is there a useful solution or a solution that you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done a little more concisely and in a way that's independent of file type...

```js
const files = ["foo.js", "foo.min.js", "bar.css","bar.min.css"];
const remove = {}

files.forEach(fn => {
  let comps = fn.split('.');
  // is the middle token min?
  if (comps.length === 3 && comps[1] === 'min') {
    // remember to remove the file without the middle token
    remove[`${comps[0]}.${comps[2]}`] = true;
  }
});
console.log(`will remove: ${Object.keys(remove)}`);

const filtered = files.filter(fn => !remove[fn]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the map to manipulate the array data to remove ".min" and Use a set for the uniqueness of filenames

```
    const files = ["foo.js", "foo.min.js", "bar.css","bar.min.css"];
    const result = [...new Set(files.map(file => file.replace('.min', '')))];
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a custom implementation of the filter

```js
const files = ["foo.js", "foo2.js", "foo2.css", "foo.min.js", "bar.css","bar.min.css"];


const result = files.filter((file) => {
  const miniPart = '.min.';
  if (file.includes(miniPart)) return true;

  const [name, extension] = file.split('.');
  const miniFile = `${name}${miniPart}${extension}`;

  return !files.includes(miniFile);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant of the theme:

```js
files = ["foo.js", "some.min.js", "foo.min.js", "bar.css","bar.min.css","abc.js"];

const excl = files.reduce((x,f)=>{
 if(f.indexOf(".min.")>0)
  x.push(f.replace(".min",""));
 return x;
}, []);

console.log(files.filter(f=>excl.indexOf(f)<0))
```